# Batch importing .sql files

Tags: linux, scripting, mysql

I have a bunch of .sql files in a directory that I need to import. Although I can do it manually, for scripting purposes I need to be able to apply them in bulk. How can I do that though? What combination of options and commands do I need?

The mysqlimport command goes like this:

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

I need to be able to add all the text files to the end. I would prefer a command than a convoluted for loop if possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use wildcards:

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name /path/to/sql/files/*
```

If there are non-SQL files in that directory, the subset of files you do want to import may have some part of their file name in common.  For instance, if they all end in `.sql`, the command becomes:

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name /path/to/sql/files/*.sql
```

If you come from DOS/Windows, it may not be clear to you why this works.  On Unixy systems, the shell expands wildcards, so the program (`mysqlimport` in this case) doesn't have to have its own processing.  That's why the usage message you quote says it expects the files to be given individually: that's how it will see the files if you use commands like the above.  The program only sees the wildcard if the pattern doesn't match anything; the shell passes it on literally to the program, having no better way of handling it.

Comment: So Bash will expand the wildcard to a list of all the matching files?

Comment: Yes.  To see this yourself, try this old hack for working around a broken/missing `ls` command: `echo /path/to/sql/files/*.sql`

Comment: Nice, this works perfectly! Thanks for pointing this out. I have no idea bash did this